# Quicklisp Libraries

Tags: file, io, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

I am currently running SBCL with quicklisp. I found an old project that I was trying to load with

> ```
>    (ql:quickload "project")
> ```

when I get the dependency error SYSTEM FILE-IO NOT FOUND. The dependencies in my project.asd file are

> ```
>    :depends-on (#:file-io #:cl-ppcre #:logv #:cl-mustache #:local-time
>            #:rutils #:alexandria)
> ```

None of the other dependencies give me any trouble, logv seems to be a discontinued log viewer, but I can't find anything concerning "file-io" in https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/releases.html. Is it just another discontinued library? Any ideas/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/wzrdsappr/file-io

Comment: https://github.com/wzrdsappr/trading-core/blob/master/trading-core.asd (most likely the project that references the dependency you gave)

Answer (score 5):

The code provided by [file-io](https://github.com/wzrdsappr/file-io/blob/master/file-io.lisp) only deals with *slurping* and *spitting* files. You can safely download the system from github and install it in Quicklisp's "local-projects" directory. Alternatively, you can use UIOP equivalent functions, which are well supported and available in most distributions.

Comment: Thanks! that's what I was looking for.